# how to edit <img> tag in the string

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
<p><img src="../../../..//js/uploads/images/selva.png" alt="" /></p>
<p>we are checkng our website</p>
<p>kfoaskf</p>
<p>asldfjas</p>
<p>jasdklfk'sd</p>
<p><img src="../../../..//js/uploads/images/images.jpg" alt="" /></p>
```

This is my string values. i need to change only this 
`<img src="../../../..//js/uploads/images/images.jpg">` to
`<img src="js/uploads/images/images.jpg">`

for every image ,i need to modify the path. 
how to do it? and my string values also differ at every time

Comment: What are all those `&nbsp;` doing there? Is it a meeting of htmlentities you implement?

Comment: replace `../../../..//js/uploads/images/images.jpg` to `js/uploads/images/images.jpg using `str_replace`

Comment: these are html page source , result of tinymce

Comment: Take a look at regex replacing too. It is more flexible.

Comment: You should use javascript

Comment: This is the output of tinymce? Oh dear - what a great tool that must be then... Anyways: you can reprogram it AFAIK. Maybe it makes sense to not produce such output in the first place?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Instead of fixing what TinyMCE does after it messes up the URLs, why don't you prevent TinyMCE from doing it in the first place? Set `document_base_url: "http://www.example.com/"` in the TinyMCE config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this bro

```
$str='<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
<p><img src="../../../..//js/uploads/images/selva.png" alt="" /></p>
<p>we are checkng our website</p>
<p>kfoaskf</p>
<p>asldfjas</p>
<p>jasdklfk\'sd</p>
<p><img src="../../../..//js/uploads/images/images.jpg" alt="" /></p>';
echo str_replace("../../../..//js/uploads/images/images.jpg","/js/uploads/images/images.jpg",$str);
```